# Loading Zend Framework 2 Config from Database

Tags: php, zend-framework2, config

I am working on a project which requires me to load configuration values from database

I have a local config file `filters.local.php` I want to remove it and put the values in database and when the application loads instead of auto loading config values from autoload folder or anyother config file, I want to mergre config from database into zend framework 2 config.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any thing you've tried so far? Like implement a method within your Application `module.php` which builds a connection to the database on each and every request or are you gonne cache it, so you don't query each and every request?

Comment: I have tried the config events method, where in Module.php's init method we trigger the event of MERGE_CONFIG but I am unable to get EntityManager in it.

Comment: As in how to get the `Doctrine\Orm\EntityManager` in your `Application\Module::onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)` - `$event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')` or show some code of what you actually tried instead. Cause this is pretty much an assumption I made due to the fact you call it the "EntityManager". Show us some of your `module.php` where you trigger the event to merge the configs so we've got an insight.

Comment: No, its not in onBootstrap, its in event callback which is attached in Module's init() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Zend Config Writer](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.config.writer.html)
.

With Zend Config Writer you can write config files with your values from database.

Example:

- In your controller

  ```
  public function writeFiltersConfigAction(){
      $config = new \Zend\Config\Config(array(), true);

      $config->filters = array();

      $citiesArray = array( 1 => Paris, 2=>London, 3=>Berlin); // Of course, these values can be taken from database

      $config->filters->cities = $citiesArray;

      $writer = new \Zend\Config\Writer\PhpArray();
      $writer->toFile('config/autoload/filters.local.php',$config);
   }
  ```
- When you will access write-filters-config in your browser, you will see that Zend Config Writer will create filters.local.php file with a php array.
- You can create a cronjob on that action, so that filters.local.php get updated how often you want
- After that, of course, you can read your config file into your application. You will read filters from the config files, avoiding databases queries every time

  ```
  $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
  $filters = $config['filters'];
  ```